# Advice required: Creating desktop application with database connectivity

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, console-application

I want to create a desktop application, I normally work on web based applications so have very little knowledge about creating console applications using .Net and visual studio.

So now in this application I'l also be using database connectivity and stored procedures (SQL server). But how should I start doing this as I dont want to install SQL server on my clients system.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the goal of your application, the amout and sturcture of the data and the environment. The last point aims to the client system, if the client is part of an enterprise network (e.g. Active Directory) or is a common user at home.

- maybe you can use xml or json files to store the data
- if you need a database, you can create a setup project for your application which automatically installs a SQL Server express
- another way is, if it's applicable for you, your application can consume a webservice which provide the data

Comment: that means if i want to use sql stored procedures..i'l have to install sql on clients system anyhow...only thing i can do is including that installation in setup file itself...

Answer (score 1):

you could use SQL Server compact http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645984(v=sql.100).aspx or SQL Lite to embark your DB in your application without external dependencies.

Otherwise, if offline isn't a requirement, you could go the "cloud" way, with web APIs